# Disable Maven Workspace Resolution in Eclipse Globally

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite

I'm currently working on multiple large webapps(each webapp when being run actually contains 3-7 eclipse projects) in Spring Tool Suite on a Mac. Every imported webapp has several errors after import and project validation complete. The maven builds will fail continually until I right click on every project associated with the given webapp and select Maven -> Disable Workspace Resolution. I can think run a maven clean, maven update, and maven build to clear out all the errors.

If there a way to disable Maven Workspace Revolution in my eclipse settings/preferences so that it's a global one time setting that tells every project in the eclipse workspace not to use Workspace Resolution?

Below are some screenshots I took to hopefully provide all the relevant details such as version numbers.

[image]

[image]

I just recently switched from using eclipse with add-ons to using the preconfigured Spring Tool Suite, so the install is only a few weeks old. It should be hopefully the most up to date versions of most plugins.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be achieved much faster by doing a Search (Ctrl-H) for `resolveWorkspaceProjects=true` for files of name `org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs`, with the scope set to Workspace, and Replace set to `resolveWorkspaceProjects=false`.

I don't believe there is a global setting to do this automatically.